# Finding homomorphism from finite abelian group G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Does there exists a homomorphism from a finite abelian group G to R*(Set of reals under multiplication) ?

**My try**:
Suppose f be non trivial homomorphism from G to R*. Since f(G) is subgroup of R* and G is finite implies R* has a finite subgroup which is other than non trivial. Now R* has only finite subgroup {1,-1} this implies f(G)= {1,-1} .Also from property of homomorphism  order of f(G) divides order of G this will conclude that  order of G is even. Now I am stuck after this.How to proceed?

Comment: That's pretty much there is: for a non-trivial homomorphism to exists, the group has to have a subgroup of index two and thus it has even order...

Comment: @DonAntonio  correct me if I am wrong sir but I think only finite subgroup of R* other than trivial is {1,-1}

Comment: @Va That is correct.

Comment: @DonAntonio  How to define a non trivial homomorphism from G to {1,-1}

Comment: @VaibhavKalia Can you find a homomorphism to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ from some particular groups you are familiar with?

Comment: @SantanaAfton  Sorry I didn't get what you are asking

Comment: @VaibhavKalia Try finding an explicit homomorphism from some finite abelian groups you are familiar with to the group $\{-1,1\}\subset\mathbb{R}$. This might give you some intuition to the answer.